# Ajax request does not call the controller on Safari and Ipad, OK on Iphone

Tags: c#, ios, ajax, model-view-controller, partial-views

When I try to call the controller to load a partial view something goes wrong in the ajax call. Does anybody else have this kind of issue?

Here is the call:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: urlBASE + 'Home/Search',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'html', // <-- to expect an html response
        success: function(result) {
            debugger;
            $('#accordion-search').html(result);
            initForm($('#search'));
            initClickSearch();
            defSearch.resolve();
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            debugger;
            console.log('jqXHR:');
            console.log(jqXHR);
            console.log('textStatus:');
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log('errorThrown:');
            console.log(errorThrown);
            alert("error : " + errorThrown)
        }
    });
```

URLbase is an 'https' link that i also use in other request (none of them is working), and the error's function is not helping because there is no information about the error, and the `HomeController` is never called (I've checked with some log). This problem is showing on:

- Ipad, all browsers
- macOS Sierra, Safari
- macOS Mojave, Safari

And same code is working on :

- Iphone 8, all browser
- macOS Sierra, Chrome
- macOS Mojave, Chrome
- Windows 10, Chrome, Firefox, Edge
- Table android
- Sony and Samsung phone

The only error I saw is this one on Mojave and on the Ipad:

> **kCFErrorHTTPParseFailure = 303**

and this one on Sierra:

> **failed to load resources. the operation couldn't be completed. Protocol error**

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Thank you

> EDIT

On mac if I go to Safari>Preferences>Confidentiality and i delete all info is working but if close and re-open Safari is having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

After some research i found the problem in the way i send the requests.

From each controller there is a call of a class that implement the http client and i have read a solution here:

https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/

The fact of having multiple 'using http client' was giving me a lot of little trouble.
After fixing the http 1 time like the tutorial everything is working fine.

Hope this help other people.